# Reordering sections, not paragraphs, in an MS word document

Tags: microsoft-word

In an MS Word document, there are two parts which have different page setup, i.e. different page margins, and different footers. For this, a section break was inserted on a page boundary.

I need to swap the order of those two sections. I could not find a way to achive this. I know how to rearrange document parts using the navigation page's header view, or the outline view's headers. Is there a similar way to easily move all pages that belong to a specific section, including that section's formattings?

I'm using MS Word 2013, and MS Word 2019 if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried cut and paste?

Comment: Yes, but I could not find how to mark the compete page **including** the section settings. The answer from Charles Kenyon explained how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no simple way. Keep in mind that the section formatting is contained in the section break that *follows* the section.

**For two sections...**

1. Go to the end of the document.
2. Insert a next-page or odd-page section break.
3. Go to the beginning of the document and select everything including the section break at the end of the first section.
4. Cut.
5. Go to the end of the document.
6. Paste

This should get you at least close to what you want. By inserting the section break at the end to paste after, you save the formatting you did have in that final section.

Here is my page on [reorganizing a document using the Navigation Pane](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm#Big_Idea_5), but that does not address section breaks, I'm afraid.

### Often you do not need the section breaks.

People often change margins when the best course would be to change the left and right paragraph indents for the styles. See [Margins and Indents in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents) on my web page.

Here is a demonstration screenshot from that page distinguishing between Margins and Indents.

> [image: screenshot]

To have different footers, often the StyleRef field will take care of that with the same footer reflecting different content on different pages to reflect the content on the page. Here is [my writing on the StyleRef field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF). Here is [Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on some of the options when you use that field](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm).

*Unneeded section breaks add to the complexity of a document. I do not know whether or not your section breaks are needed.*

**References**

- [Working With Sections](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/WorkWithSections.htm) - MVP page
- [Sections, Headers and Footers](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm) on my site.

Comment: Thanks. This did what I needed, except I can't seem to find out how to get rid of the additional page that was added at the end by inserting the section break.

Comment: My recollection is that @macropod (Paul Edstein) has produced a macro to do this. It requires copying all of the section settings from the Next Page section break to the one at the end of the document. He may weigh in here with at least a link if my memory is correct.

Comment: I've found this description [If you really want to delete the temporary section break](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/WorkWithSections.htm#DeletingSectionBreak%20...) which helps to get rid of that added section break.